# How to select a given feature in a GeoJSON file using Python?

Tags: python, geojson, features

**Scenario:**

I have a large (120+ MB) .geojson file that represents a bunch of `LineStrings` features.

Here is an example `feature` selected using `json.dumps(geoFile['features'][0])`:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 0,
    "properties": {
        "FID": 0,
        "prop1": 1,
        "prop2": "thing2",
        "prop3": "thing3"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -99.491525,
                35.306851,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491485,
                35.306705,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491451,
                35.306581,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491417,
                35.306456,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491375,
                35.306321,
                0
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Goal:**

- Select a `feature` based on the property value in `prop1`.
- Render the selected `feature` on a `geopandas` map (or other python map) along with some georeferenced points from dataframes being used elsewhere in the app.

**Questions:**

- What is the Python syntax for selecting the `feature` from the GeoJSON file based on `properties/prop`?

  - Obviously I know how to select based on feature index (`[0]` above), but I can't find examples of selecting by `prop1`.
  - **Tried:** `json.dumps(geoFile['features'][0]['properties']['prop1'] == 1)` but this just returns `true`

Comment: Also tried this to no avail. Get `Key error` on `properties`.

`with open('file.geojson') as f:
    python_obj = json.load(f)

for prop1 in python_obj["properties"]["prop1 "]:
    if prop1 == 1:
        prop1 
        break
else:
    # Some default action
    print("No prop1 found")

print("Value:", prop1 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go this way, tell me if this fits your needs:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
feat = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 0,
    "properties": {
        "FID": 0,
        "prop1": 1,
        "prop2": "thing2",
        "prop3": "thing3"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -99.491525,
                35.306851,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491485,
                35.306705,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491451,
                35.306581,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491417,
                35.306456,
                0
            ],
            [
                -99.491375,
                35.306321,
                0
            ]
        ]
    }
}
type(feat) # it's a dict
# I let you adapt this to your full file,
# it should be "almost" straightforward once your file has been read:
gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(feat), orient='columns')
gdf['geometry']=gdf['geometry.coordinates'].apply(lambda l: LineString(l))
```

Then `gdf` should look like:

[image: Resulting feature]

Based on that, you can extract your features based on your preferred column, such as for example:

```
gdf[gdf['properties.prop1']==1] # or whatever number you want
```

You can also explore its geometry as a shapely geometry:

```
print(type(gdf[gdf['properties.prop1']==1]['geometry'].iloc[0]))
<class 'shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString'>
```

You may also be interested to set a [CRS](https://geopandas.org/projections.html#setting-a-projection):

```
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"
```

You can then plot your geometry using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='blue')
plt.grid()
```

Which gives:

[image: matplotlib result]

Or with [Folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) for example:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map([35.3065, -99.4914], zoom_start=19)

folium.Choropleth(
    gdf['geometry'],
    line_weight=2,
    line_color='green'
).add_to(m)

m
```

Which results in:

[image: Folium result]

### One last piece of advice:

Your object, as you shared it, has permit to build the above piece of codes. But it may happen that it's only a sub-part of a larger json object, with some higher level object encapsulating this one. In that case you probably need to access your properties, after having flatten the json object into the GeoDataFrame, such as: `gdf['metaclass.features.geometry.coordinates']` for example.
To adapt to your real situation, I could only suggest you to explore your GeoDataFrame object using `gdf.head()` or `gdf.describe()` or `gdf.columns`.

### More to read:

https://anitagraser.com/2019/10/31/interactive-plots-for-geopandas-geodataframe-of-linestrings/

Comment: I wish I could shake your hand right now. Thank you for the path you lined out. This is great.

Comment: Getting a `Key error: 'properties.prop1` when I try to use my own .geojson file. `locations = gpd.read_file('myfile.geojson')` then `locations(type)` yields `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame`. Assuming because this is already a GeoDataFrame I can skip the `gdf` commands above. `locations` yields a table just like `gdf` command above. BUT `locations[locations['properties.prop1']==1]` returns the error: `KeyError: 'properties.prop1'` Thoughts on this one?

Comment: Hm... `locations = gpd.read_file('myfile.geojson')` then `type(locations)` = `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame`. Then trying `gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(locations), orient='columns')` yields `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Hm...`with open('myfile.geojson') as f: data = json.load(f)` then `type(locations` = `dict`. Subsequently, `gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(data), orient='columns')` works without issue BUT `gdf['geometry']=gdf['geometry.coordinates'].apply(lambda l: LineString(l))` yields `KeyError: 'geometry.coordinates'`.